# We're Hiring page does not list jobs

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

The link has passed so I don't have a copy of it at this time but I saw a link on the side that StackOverflow was hiring.

I doubt I have any of the qualifications they are looking for but I was curious. When I clicked on the link I was simply [shown the Company page and a list of perks](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-overflow?c=62IeP5BU9xQoV2).

Seems like a simple question but does that link only show the actual jobs if you have a careers profile? Sure I suppose I could make a profile just to answer my question but I only really have scripting experience so I never saw a point.

Answer (score 26):

Our company page doesn't currently show any jobs because our people team is working through a backlog of applications. We stopped advertising the open positions through Careers temporarily while we catch up – we are still hiring, and the listings will be back again soon. It has nothing to do with whether or not you have a Careers profile; jobs listed on the Stack Overflow Careers job board are always visible to anonymous users as well.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. Does that mean I saw the advert in error? As a side note you get votes fast.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what exactly you saw, @Matt. We have a bunch of different ad types that run...we do advertise company pages on their own, so it's possible you saw one that was just supposed to display how awesome the company is, rather than advertising any specific hiring needs we may have.

Comment: Pretty sure it was something along the lines of Come work for StackOverflow.... We're Hiring with a picture of, what I presume is, a human wearing a horse/unicorn mask. It seemed obvious that I would get to a job list. No matter. I know now.

Comment: @Matt Sorry, that was our fault. We should have paused those ads. The proper people have been reprimanded :)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tC9DY.png

Comment: @Matt: So their jobs are listed on that page now? ;)